# Is it possible that nested loop joins different data to same id in different loops

Tags: sql, oracle, resultset

We have an interesting phenomenon with a sql and the oracle database that we could not reproduce. The example was simplified. We believe not, but possibly oversimplified.

**Main question:** Given a nested loop, where the inner (not driving) table has an analytic function, whose result is ambiguous (multiple rows could be the first row of the order by), would it be feasible that said analytic function can return different results for different outer loops?

**Secondary Question:** *If yes*, how can we reproduce this behaviour?
*If no*, have you any other ideas why this query would produce multiple rows for the same company.
Not the question: Should the assumption on what is wrong be correct, correcting the sql would be easy. Just make the order by in the analytic function unambiguous e.g. by adding the id column as second criteria.

**Problem:**
Company has a n:m relation to owner and a 1:n relation to address.
The SQL joins all tables while reading only a single address per company making use of the analytic function row_number(), groups by company AND address and accumulates the owner name.
We use the query for multiple purposes, other purposes involve reading the “best” address, the problematic one does not. We got multiple error reports with results like this:
Company A has owners N1, N2, N3.
Result was

| Company | Owner list |
| --- | --- |
| A | N1 |
| A | N2, N3 |

All cases that were reported involve companies with multiple “best” addresses, hence the theory, that somehow the subquery that should deliver a single address is broken. But we could not reproduce the result.

**Full Details:**
(for smaller numbers the listagg() is the original function used, but it fails for bigger numbers. count(*) should be a suitable replacement)

```
--cleanup
DROP TABLE rau_companyowner;
DROP TABLE rau_owner;
DROP TABLE rau_address;
DROP TABLE rau_company;

--create structure
CREATE TABLE rau_company (
id NUMBER CONSTRAINT pk_rau_company PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX (CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_rau_company_p ON rau_company(id))
);

CREATE TABLE rau_owner (
id NUMBER CONSTRAINT pk_rau_owner PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX (CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_rau_owner_p ON rau_owner(id)),
name varchar2(1000)
);

CREATE TABLE rau_companyowner (
company_id NUMBER,
owner_id NUMBER,
CONSTRAINT pk_rau_companyowner PRIMARY KEY (company_id, owner_id) USING INDEX (CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_rau_companyowner_p ON rau_companyowner(company_id, owner_id)),
CONSTRAINT fk_companyowner_company FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES rau_company(id),
CONSTRAINT fk_companyowner_owner FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES rau_owner(id)
);

CREATE TABLE rau_address (
id NUMBER CONSTRAINT pk_rau_address PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX (CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_rau_address_p ON rau_address(id)),
company_id NUMBER,
prio NUMBER NOT NULL,
street varchar2(1000),
CONSTRAINT fk_address_company FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES rau_company(id)
);

--create testdata
DECLARE
   TYPE t_address IS TABLE OF rau_address%rowtype INDEX BY pls_integer;
   address t_address;
   TYPE t_owner IS TABLE OF rau_owner%rowtype INDEX BY pls_integer;
   owner t_owner;
   TYPE t_companyowner IS TABLE OF rau_companyowner%rowtype INDEX BY pls_integer;
   companyowner t_companyowner;
   ii pls_integer;
   company_id pls_integer := 1;
   test_count PLS_INTEGER := 10000;
   --test_count PLS_INTEGER := 50;
BEGIN
   --rau_company
   INSERT INTO rau_company VALUES (company_id);
   --rau_owner,rau_companyowner
   FOR ii IN 1 .. test_count
   LOOP
      owner(ii).id:=ii;
      owner(ii).name:='N'||to_char(ii);
      companyowner(ii).company_id:=company_id;
      companyowner(ii).owner_id:=ii;
   END LOOP;
   forall ii IN owner.FIRST .. owner.LAST
      INSERT INTO rau_owner VALUES (owner(ii).id, owner(ii).name);
   forall ii IN companyowner.FIRST .. companyowner.LAST
      INSERT INTO rau_companyowner VALUES (companyowner(ii).company_id, companyowner(ii).owner_id);
   --rau_address
   FOR ii IN 1 .. test_count
   LOOP
      address(ii).id:=ii;
      address(ii).company_id:=company_id;
      address(ii).prio:=1;
      address(ii).street:='S'||to_char(ii);
   END LOOP;
   forall ii IN address.FIRST .. address.LAST
      INSERT INTO rau_address VALUES (address(ii).id, address(ii).company_id, address(ii).prio, address(ii).street);
   COMMIT;
END;

-- check testdata
SELECT 'rau_company' tab, COUNT(*) count FROM rau_company
UNION all
SELECT 'rau_owner', COUNT(*) FROM rau_owner
UNION all
SELECT 'rau_companyowner', COUNT(*) FROM rau_companyowner
UNION all
SELECT 'rau_address', COUNT(*) FROM rau_address;

-- the sql: NL with address as inner loop enforced
-- ‘order BY prio’ is ambiguous because all addresses have the same prio
--   => the single row in ad could be any row
   SELECT /*+ leading(hh hhoo oo ad) use_hash(hhoo oo) USE_NL(hh ad) */
          hh.id company,
          ad.street,
--          LISTAGG(oo.name || ', ') within group (order by oo.name) owner_list,
          count(oo.id) owner_count
     FROM rau_company hh
LEFT JOIN rau_companyowner hhoo ON hh.id = hhoo.company_id
LEFT JOIN rau_owner oo ON hhoo.owner_id = oo.id
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT *
            FROM (
                 SELECT company_id, street,
                        row_number() over ( partition by company_id order BY prio asc ) as row_num                       
                   FROM rau_address                     
                 )
           WHERE row_num = 1              
          ) ad ON hh.id = ad.company_id  
 GROUP BY hh.id,
          ad.street;
```

Comment: "...would it be feasible that said analytic function can return different results for different outer loops..." -- Yes. You can simply use a random function to reproduce the bahevior.

Comment: It could between different calls, but I don't see how you're getting that within a single call. Your current result shows a company name (?) and no street, which doesn't really match your example code. Is it feasible that you have non-integer company IDs? And have you run the simple fix to the query against the environment that behaves like this, to check your assumption? (Also, I guess, what version/patch level of Oracle are you seeing this in; and are that environment and where you're trying to reproduce on the same version/patch level? Are there any unusual or hidden init parameters?)

Comment: The base query does return the street, but it is used in different contexts. The problem occurs in a context, which does not use street. I used the street while trying to reproduce the problem. Would the query on address indeed return different rows on different iterations of the NL we would see it in the street, but it does not. <br>
Company name is due to the simplification. Should have called it company id.

Comment: I run this test against the same version, but different server (dev test). The original problem is not reproducible, which means we get the error report, ask the user to repeat it and the error does not show again, 99% sure data has not changed in between.

Comment: --random as suggested by The Impaler        
    SELECT /*+ leading(hh hhoo oo ad) use_hash(hhoo oo) USE_NL(hh ad) */
          hh.id company,
          ad.street,
          LISTAGG(oo.name || ', ') within group (order by oo.name)
     FROM rau_company hh
LEFT JOIN rau_companyowner hhoo ON hh.id = hhoo.company_id
LEFT JOIN rau_owner oo ON hhoo.owner_id = oo.id
LEFT JOIN (
                 SELECT DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('x',4) street                       
                   FROM dual
          ) ad ON 1=1  
 GROUP BY hh.id,
          ad.street;

Comment: Using Random as Impaler suggested obviously produces the problem. But for me the question remains, if an “order by” would really flip its order within the same call on multiple executions of a NL and if it would how to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cris Saxon was so nice to answer my question: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9546263400346154452

In short: As long as the order by is ambiguous (non-deterministic), there will always be a chance for different results even within the same sql.

To reproduce add this to my test data:
ALTER TABLE rau_address PARALLEL 8;
and try the select at the bottom, it should deliver multiple rows.